# undefined index yii in forgot password

Tags: php, yii, forgot-password

I am working in yii and creating forgot password. i try to use http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/744/how-to-create-forgot-password-in-yii-sending-email-to-reset-password/ for forgot password same as https://github.com/ruderbytes/forgot-password-in-yii.
but i have an error **Undefined index: Lupa**  which is in the action forgot $getEmail line.

```
 public function actionForgot()
     {
        $getEmail=$_POST['Lupa']['email'];
        $getModel= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$getEmail));
        if(isset($_POST['Lupa']))
        {
            $getToken=rand(0, 99999);
            $getTime=date("H:i:s");
            $getModel->token=md5($getToken.$getTime);
            $namaPengirim="Owner Jsource Indonesia";
            $emailadmin="fahmi.j@programmer.net";
            $subjek="Reset Password";
            $setpesan="you have successfully reset your password<br/>
                <a href='http://yourdomain.com/index.php?r=site/vertoken/view&token=".$getModel->token."'>Click Here to Reset Password</a>";
            if($getModel->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($namaPengirim).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subjek).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$emailadmin}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$emailadmin}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
            $getModel->save();
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('forgot','link to reset your password has been sent to your email');
            mail($getEmail,$subject,$setpesan,$headers);
            $this->refresh();
        }

        }
    $this->render('forgot');
}
```

can anyone have suggetion thank you in advance.

Comment: `isset($_POST['Lupa'])` should be at the start of the function.

Comment: that is already done after that but i don't understand first thing

Comment: @user3423920 just print your POST and check data. in action - var_dump($_POST);die();

Comment: @user3423920 You got an error because in array $_POST not exist key `Lupa`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public function actionForgot()
     {
        $getEmail=$_POST['Lupa']['email'];
        $getModel= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$getEmail));
        if(isset($_POST['Lupa']))
        { //..
```

To:

```
public function actionForgot()
     {
        if(isset($_POST['Lupa']) && isset($_POST['Lupa']['email'])) {
           $getEmail=$_POST['Lupa']['email'];
           $getModel= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$getEmail));
//...
```